# `coqc -Q`returns "coqc: -Q: no such file or directory"

Tags: coq

When I try to compile files with `coqc -Q . LF`, I get the error:

```
coqc: -Q: no such file or directory
```

`coqc` information:

```
The Coq Proof Assistant, version 8.4pl6 (December 2020)
compiled on Dec 02 2020 23:06:36 with OCaml 4.02.0
```

What's strange is that it worked previously for me. I formatted my disk to the same exact OS, installed the same exact opam, yet I'm getting an error where I didn't before.
Also using `8.4.6` for legacy reasons.

Comment: Could it be that you are in an inconsistent state with respect to the operating system.  For instance, your shell maybe in a directory that was removed in another existing window.

Comment: @Yves What does that mean? Also, I am using the same exact OS that I previously ran 8.4.6 on...

Comment: What is that OS exactly?

Comment: I am trying to reproduce the conditions of your experiment, btw.

Comment: I just looked in the documentation of for coq 8.4 at the following address and I don't find any `-Q` option.  https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.4pl6/refman/Reference-Manual016.html#hevea_default822

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 8.4.6 of Coq does not support a `-Q` option, this can be confirmed by looking in the manual, where no such option is documented.  I also checked in the source files: they can be downloaded from `https://github.com/coq/coq/releases/tag/V8.4pl6`.  a systematic search of string `-R` shows that it does appear in file `scripts/coqc.ml` but no string `-Q` appears anywhere in the sources.

You did not tell us the whole story.  You are not reproducing exactly the same attempt... You must have been using a more recent version until now.